# What are the different skins in Agar.io?

Tags: agar.io

I've noticed in [Agar.io](http://Agar.io) there are a number of different skins when you choose specific usernames.

For example, entering Moon, Earth or Mars shows you as that particular celestial body.

Is there a list of the rest?

Answer (score 14):

Here is a list that gets updated as more skins get added: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kXQDhQEr

A name/skin comparison would be nice, but it's the best I could find.

The list as of today is:

Alphabetical order:

- 2ch.hk
- 4chan
- 8
- 8ch
- 9gag
- argentina
- australia
- austria
- ayy lmao
- bait
- bangladesh
- <strike>Belarus</strike> (removed)
- belgium
- bosnia
- botswana
- brazil
- bulgaria
- byzantium
- cambodia
- canada
- chile
- china
- cia
- confederate
- Croatia
- cuba
- denmark
- doge
- ea
- earth
- estonia
- european union
- facebook
- facepunch
- feminism
- finland
- france
- french kingdom
- german empire
- germany
- greece
- <strike>hitler</strike> (removed)
- hong kong
- hungary
- imperial japan
- india
- indiana
- indonesia
- iran
- iraq
- ireland
- irs
- italy
- jamaica
- japan
- kc
- latvia
- lithuania
- luxembourg
- maldivas
- mars
- matriarchy
- mexico
- moon
- nasa
- <strike>Nazi</strike> (removed)
- netherlands
- nigeria
- north korea
- norway
- origin
- pakistan
- patriarchy
- peru
- piccolo
- pokerface
- poland
- portugal
- prodota
- prussia
- qing dynasty
- quebec
- receita federal
- reddit
- romania
- russia
- sanik
- satanist
- scotland
- sealand
- sir
- somalia
- south korea
- spain
- stalin
- steam
- stussy
- sweden
- switzerland
- taiwan
- texas
- thailand
- tsarist russia
- tumblr
- turkey
- ukraine
- united kingdom
- usa
- ussr
- vinesauce
- wojak
- yaranaika

Answer (score 10):

### Using new skins in Agario

To use any of the skins, all you have to do is enter the skin name as your username, before entering a game. **You can see the name of each skin by hovering over the image.**

### Adding new skins to Agario

The developers appear to update the game quite regularly. On top of that, they are known to respond quite well to fan suggestion. [**You can post new skin suggestions here**](https://www.reddit.com/r/Agario/comments/34r8n0/post_your_skins_here_and_the_dev_might_add_them/), however, they request that an actual skin draft is posted - not just an idea. If you want a turkey riding a salad, post the picture of the turkey riding the salad.

As more skins go up, I invite users to add them, below. I will try, as I become aware of them. When a skin is removed, it should be moved to the discontinued area, rather then completely deleted. **Please be aware that some may find the discontinued skins offensive.**

### The Skins

The following are the skins in the official version of the game. Please note that you won't find any skins here that are unique to a modification of the game, and that some skins use transparency, which is difficult to accurately display on a website.

#### Flags and Emblems

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Groups and Communities

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Faces

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Political Leaders

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Space

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Miscellaneous

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Discontinued

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer is set up so that other users may update it as necessary. Please try and keep the same format. Each skin is its own image, so they may be individually re-ordered, or deleted, if necessary.

Comment: There isn't any way to caption with markdown. Since we can't use tables (not the ASCII ones), your best bet is to ugily put the name in-line after each image. Otherwise, the `alt` text is your only method for neatness.

Comment: Also link 15 is broken.

Comment: Here's something I wasn't sure of, tho. OP asks what the different skins are. I interpret this as "what are the playable skins". Should I include the skins that were removed? Most are things like Hitler, Nazi, Isis. There's one or two that appear to have been removed for some other reason (I can't immediately see why they would be offensive)

Comment: I think the first poster has already done a good job of documenting everything.. Even if it doesn't look all out flash-y and graphic-y like yours... Plus you aren't really adding anything new, apart from images; it's better still to just edit them into the original (Sheepolution's) post.

Comment: As is, it's quite incomplete. Had to go out, so I posted what I had. I had intended to post it as a community wiki, but realised this just let's anybody edit it, which really, they can do anyway (just, as is it has a little more protection). I felt , without images, players would have to follow links off site to pick a skin without a whole bunch of trial and error.

Comment: I think this is a much more useful answer than the other answer as not only does it display all the skins in a far more compact way, it also explains how to use the skins and gives a preview or what each one is.

Comment: @Aequitas And it's also pretty much useless on mobile devices because "hovering" is not a thing you can do

Comment: Now I want a "turkey riding the salad" skin.