# How do you change your skin?

Tags: agar.io

How do you change your skin in the online multiplayer game agar.io?
 I see other players floating around looking like earth and sanic ect...
How do I make a skin or choose one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each skin is associated to a name. So, if you want to have "earth" skin, you have to call yourself "earth", if you want the USA flag, call yourself "usa", etc. The names are not case-sensitive.

A full list is available on [agarioskins.org](http://www.agarioskins.org/), as well as [here on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/229595/116528) !

Comment: This list is outdated, some of the skins aren't available anymore.

Comment: @Alagaros Happy now ? :D

Comment: never been happier.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if making skins work. However, there is a whole list of skins. You can see them in this website:
http://www.agarioskins.org/
Also, the most popular ones I've seen are "doge," "sanik," "earth," "usa," etc.
Have fun playing Agar.io! It's really fun!

PS: You have to type the word (spelled correctly) in the "Nickname" box in order to make sure that the skin works. If your computer lags, you may not see the skins for the first 30 seconds of playing. It has happened to me before.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do on www.agar.io or en.agar.bio is type in the name of the skin you want as your name.

I know that if you're on en.agar.bio, you can see the list by clicking on the settings icon and then clicking on the Avatar Gallery button.